# create gantt chart in other views

Tags: excel, bar-chart, excel-2003, vba

Let's say I have a table (Table1) with the following columns and data:

```
Table1
Task    StartDate   EndDate
A      01-Jan       31-Jan
B      04-Feb       28-Feb
C      10-Feb       10-Mar
D      12-Mar       10-Apr
```

Apart from Gantt Chart we already have in excel2003, if possible, how can I make configure charts/tables with the following 2 views?

It is expected Table1 data is provided from colleagues and view1 and 2 will be generated automatically.

Millions thanks in advance!

```
(view 1)
Period (taken from StartDate/EndDate)   A   B   C   D

01-Jan to 31-Jan                      X days
04-Feb to 28-Feb                          X days    
10-Feb to 10-Mar                               X days
12-Mar to 10 Apr                                     X days
```

```
(view 2)
Jan Feb Mar Apr
A   
    B   
    C   C
        D   D
```

Answer (score 0):

"Automatically" may mean you want VBA but since not tagged as such, assuming `Task` is in A1 etc:

VIEW 1

Copy and Paste Transpose A2:A5 to E1.
Enter `=IF($A2=E$1,$C2-$B2,"")` in E2 and copy across and down to H5. Format to suit.

VIEW 2

Enter 1/1/13 in J1, `=EOMONTH(J1,1)` in K1 and copy across. Format to suit.
Enter `=IF(OR(MONTH($B2)=MONTH(J$1),MONTH($C2)=MONTH(J$1)),$A2,"")` in J2 and copy across and down to M5.

Comment: Thanks a lot guru! But have a question here, in case there is a taskE lasting for more than 2 months, e.g. start in Jan and end in Mar, the task is shown under Jan and Mar but not in Feb. Is it possible to display it?